# How secure is the Parse PFUser.current() object?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-framework

I have a question about Parse security and hope someone can give me some pointers and suggestions.

I am working on a game where users can accumulate a game resource called gold.

To keep track of how much gold each user has, I have a Parse class called Resource. This class is public readable (thru get, not find) but not public writable.

The User class and the Resource class are linked both ways in that:
each object in the User class has a property called resourceId, which is the `objectId` of the Resource object that belongs to the user. Therefore, players can read (thru get) his own resource as well as those of his friends; and
each object in the Resource class has a pointer that points to a user in the User class

In the game, a user can spin a prize wheel to get gold prizes. When the user spins the wheel, the client calls a cloud code function and pass on a single argument, which is the `PFUser.current()` object.

The cloud code generates a random number to determines the prize, and then write the prize to the Resource class. To determine which Resource object to write to, the cloud code does 2 things:
(1) it reads the `resourceId` from the argument `(PFUser.current())`, and
(2) using that `resourceId`, it gets the relevant Resource object, then checks to see if the user-pointer points to the same User object as the argument itself (again, `PFUser.current()`).

So my question is, is my setup secure against someone trying to spin the prize wheel of another user? Can a compromised client device modifies the `PFUser.current()` object and pretend to be another user? Are there better ways to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunction", function (request, response) {

var senderUser = request.user;

//your code

});
```

It's definitely better way than passing `PFUser.current()` as an argument - it works with the Parse SDK internally, which means it should be harder to fake it than the argument.